# How may I delete a .xml file from my Droid Project?

Tags: android

I'm new in Android Development so I got (I think so) an epic easy problem to solve but I still can't do it..
How may I delete a .xml file from my Droid Project?

I'm trying to simple press "Delete" to do it but I receive an error that says:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like aapt may have failed and left eclipse in a weird state. Make sure calc_auto.xml doesn't have any errors in it. If it does, make sure you fix them, especially, as suggested [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20836), any errors with the xmlns:android attribute.

If you still can't delete it after that, [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/utnUiNIGgmA) mentions that after fixing the XML file, you can try opening up the Problems view (Window->Show View->Problems on a Mac) and deleting the error. Then modify a few files and try running it to force a rebuild.

Eclipse with ADT is a great tool, but can sometimes end up in weird states, especially when aapt is parsing through your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all processes using that xml file.close java files or xml files with references to that xml file and restart eclipse.Then try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I justed restarted the eclipse and it worked out